# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) not supported on JDK 9+ While using Java 8 in m y eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, okhttp, java-9, sslsocketfactory

In my project i'm using java 8 and same is configured in mu pom.xml as well as in my eclipse. But whenever i try to compile my code via mvn install then it's throwing below error.
I'm also not using SSLSocketFactory in my code any where.  And this started suddenly with all my project in eclipse recently.

```html
Exception in thread "DefaultMetadataResolver-0-1" [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------Exception in thread "DefaultMetadataResolver-0-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory)
not supported on JDK 9+ at okhttp3.internal.platform.Jdk9Platform.trustManager(Jdk9Platform.java:78) at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.sslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:650) at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.
<init>(OkHttpAetherClient.java:98) at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.newAetherClient(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:276)[INFO] BUILD FAILURE at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.
  <init>(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:191) [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:89) at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:603) at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
    Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[INFO] Total time: 1.086 s [INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-17T15:07:54-04:00 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory)
    not supported on JDK 9+ at okhttp3.internal.platform.Jdk9Platform.trustManager(Jdk9Platform.java:78) at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.sslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:650) at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.
    <init>(OkHttpAetherClient.java:98) [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/491M [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.newAetherClient(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:276)
      at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.
      <init>(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:191) at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:89) at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:603) at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
        Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [ERROR] clientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory) not supported on JDK 9+
```

My Pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.baml.baats.baats_reports_services
    baats_reports_services
    war

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springboot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <release.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</release.version>
    <build.number>0</build.number>
    <ignite.version>2.7.6</ignite.version>
</properties>


<version>${release.version}-${build.number}</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.baml.baats.baats_common</groupId>
        <artifactId>baats-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-27</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.baml.etoefds.connect_services_core</groupId>
        <artifactId>connect-services-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- Spring Framework Caching Support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>libs-release</name>
        <url>http://code-artifacts.bankofamerica.com:18081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>libs-snapshot</name>
        <url>http://code-artifacts.bankofamerica.com:18081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>src/main/resources/zip.xml</descriptor>
                        <finalName>baats_reports_services-properties-${release.version}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: where is yours `JAVA_HOME` points to?

Comment: its C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8

Comment: if you use maven or gradle, could you please provide your pom.xml or build.gradle file?

Comment: added it in my question

Answer (score 1):

This is a possibly a bug for https://github.com/takari/aether-connector-okhttp.  This only seems to happen if Aether itself can't get the trust manager.

https://github.com/takari/aether-connector-okhttp/blob/master/src/main/java/io/takari/aether/okhttp/OkHttpAetherClient.java#L113

The OkHttpClient.Builder.sslSocketFactory method is deprecated (4 years ago) for a long time now, and specifically not supported on JDK9+ because of module system changes and also it's use of implementation details of Oracle JDK 8, which don't hold on 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 etc.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/85f74e2004eaf0d4ff339e8644df3d8e716361e5

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.12.x/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/platform/Jdk9Platform.java#L84-L91